# Problem with GDAL_warp

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I'm tryng to use the tool gdalwarp, but in some cases there is an alert that say:

> Warning 1: Self-intersection at or near point 2647000 4441118.8085795399
>   ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.

Can you tell me how to fix the input shape and solve this problem of "self-intersection"?

```
shape_filtered=outShapefile
warp_opts=gdal.WarpOptions(format="GTiff", cutlineDSName=shape_filtered, cropToCutline=True, dstAlpha = True )

res=gdal.Warp(output_dir+input_raster[-10:-4]+"_"+cod+".tif", input_raster, options=warp_opts)
print (res)
```

Comment: It's a problem with the input polygon/s. You can fix most things in simple features with a zero-width buffer, because the geometry engine has to decompose the polygons or lines to a topological graph, from which degenerate meanders within these path (turtle-graphics) structures can be detected and removed by an automatic process. It may well not be a good fix for the actual problem but it probably is fine. If you (redundantly) ogr2ogr your vector layer to a new file (maybe not shapefile) it might fix it in much the same way (indirectly, but usefully).

Comment: Please add more details. How do you exactly call gdalwarp, please provide a code snippet. How does the cutline Polygon look like?

Comment: please add the cutline polygon WKT to the question

Comment: Finally to add to my long comment above, the problem is a self-loop in one polygon ring, where it intersects "itself" by overlapping. It happens commonly in automated digitizing from images, and less commonly in manual drawing (the turtle went a way it's not allowed to, because it can't go over or under the path it is on - but it also can't see where it's going because it's head is down, stuck in the plane ...).